# Error for Google Maps on BlackBerry Browser

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, blackberry

I am unable to view Google Maps on my BlackBerry 9900 (OS 7.1) browser. I have successfully installed the Google Map App and able to use it. However, I have a requirement to open a Google Map URL received in a SMS. When I try to open `maps.google.com` or a specific url `http://maps.google.com/maps?q=25.34567,55.12345+(xxx%xxx%xxx` it gives me the following error:

> Error
>   A network error occurred
>   Please try again later

Is there any work around to get Google maps to load on the BlackBerry browser?

**EDIT:** The URL in the PC browser opens by adding a closing `)` and automatically updates to `https://www.google.com/maps/place/25%C2%B020'26.2%22N+55%C2%B029'21.2%22E/@25.3406166,55.489217,15z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0`. I tried in the BlackBerry broswer with `https://www.google.com/maps/preview?q=25.34567,55.12345+(xxx%xxx%xxx)` and the improvement here is that I do not see the error message but instead a blank page with the `Google Maps` icon on the window.

Comment: Are you opening the URL in the browser or in the maps app? If it is in the browser: are you able to open the same URL in a desktop browser? Are you able to open any other URL in the blackberry browser?

Comment: And why have you tagged the question as Android? OS 7.1 is Java, only BB10 OS is able to run Android apps.

Comment: I am able to open the URL in a desktop browser by adding a closing bracket `)` to the URL. The same still does not work on the BlackBerry browser. Please see edit in the question above.